# can't find position of 3rd point in triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

[image]
Here i want to find (x2,y2). All 3 angles(A,B,C) are known.
All 3 sides length are known(a,b,c). How should i do it? and also (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) are known.

Comment: If you know the two points and all the angles, all you need to do is find the equations of the sides and get their intersection(s). There will be 2 triangles possible with this information.

Comment: C is lying on the intersection of two circles, one centered at $A$ with radius $b$. the other centered at $B$ with radius $a$.

Comment: ok. but after solving them i'm getting two points. how do i find a point which lies counter clockwise direction from line AB. and yes in my problem their is always two intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is at the intersection of a circle of radius $b$ around point $A$ and a circle of radius $a$ around $B$.  Write the two equations and solve them simultaneously.  You don't need the angles if you have those two sides.  You will get two solutions for the position of $C$, one above and one below $AB$.

Comment: ok. but after solving them i'm getting two points. how do i find a point which lies counter clockwise direction from line AB. and yes in my problem their is always two intersections.

Comment: I said you would get two points (unless the triangle is a straight line and the circles are tangent).  If you think about drawing the circles you should be able to see that.  Probably the easiest way to pick the counterclockwise one is to compute $AB \times AC$ for each point and pick the one that gives a vector pointing towards you.  You can also compute the slopes but that takes sorting through cases.

Comment: ok. AB*AC i.e doing vector product to get the resulting vector with its direction. thank u.